# use gradle to compile any android project in first time,gradle.zip always download again?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

ext:
OS: **window8  x64**
android studio **2.1.3**
gradle plugin **2.1.3**
gradle **2.14.1**

I have already download `gradle-2.14.1.zip` when compile project last time, use `git clone` project from github, modify `graldw-plugin` version and `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` in `graldle-wrapper.properties`

In embed Terminal run `gradlew build` it download gradle again,[like this(sorry pic not allow enbed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzJai.jpg) (redundant file take up more C disk rest space) how to solve?